# Azure Webjobs Control Panel?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am wondering if there are any solutions for a 'Control Panel' like functionality for Azure Webjobs?  We have a webapp that has a few different webjobs.  For example, we have a daily 'db cleanup' method as well as one that sends out billing notifications.  We also have methods that pull in data from various 3rd party systems every 5 minutes.  All in all, about a dozen different little jobs here and there.  Most are triggered using a CRON timer trigger.

I would like to have some sort of 'dashboard/Control Panel' where I can quickly see all the functions within all the webjobs (although I could easily move all the functions to 1 webjob).  It would show last run time, last run status, next run time, and have the ability to 'pause' a function from running (as well as resume).  I know I can do all this by literally stopping the entire WebJob in Azure but then it ends up stopping other functions that I may not want to.  I also don't want to have 20 webjobs each with 1 function.  Any solutions that have been developed?  Is there a Dashboard that works like that with Azure Functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Azure has Control panel for webjobs.

Open url https://YOUR_APP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/ -> Tools -> Web Jobs dashboard

Or Open your app -> In menu search advanced tools
[image: Advanced tools]

Comment: Sorry - I should have said I knew about Kudu already.  Yes, it is a dashboard where you can see your jobs (although it appears that the function status and reporting has moved to Application Insights).  The problem with Kudu and App Insights is that you can't pause/resume the jobs or the functions.

Comment: @MikeSmith not clear on what you try to achive but have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Comment: So that kind of if you want to orchestrate calling to your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't have to have all functions in one Functions.cs file, you could have multiple multiple webjobs and in one webjob there could be multiple function files(Functions.cs, Function1.cs etc).

[image]

Then for now if you have a bunch of functions in one webjob, you could only manage one whole webjob. If your webjob is continuous, you could stop it in the portal or kill the process in the kudu. Then your webjob will be in stopped or pending restart status.

[image]

If you still want to manage each one function in one webjob, suppose you have to try the Azure Function.

Comment: Thx for reply.  Unfortunately with the newest version of Webjobs, it doesn't list the functions in Kudu like this anymore (things are reported via Application Insights).  I do understand that I could use process explorer to 'kill' apps but this is using a bazooka when i just need a flyswatter.  Ultimately, I think the answer is 'no' - there isn't a granular way to pause/resume individual functions/triggers.

Answer (score 0):

As part of project Kudu - Kudu is the engine behind git/hg deployments, WebJobs, and various other features in Azure Web Sites, there is a web jobs API available. You can get more details from here - [WebJobs API Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API).

You can get details of all Web Jobs using - `GET /api/webjobs` method, the response contains the status of the webjobs. I am using PowerShell to Monitor my web jobs. Here is some psuedo code which will help you to get started.

```
$authHeader = "Basic 3946239864237492789f9df987d7f7s97f987s8d977sd978979f8s77f9797w9e7987e="

$fullAuthHeader = @{
    Authorization = $authHeader
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/$schedulerEntry -Headers $fullAuthHeader -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
$output = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The `$output` is a Json object, you can loop through and get details.